# Can MKV hold multiple images in sequence (i.e. slideshow?)

Tags: video, compression

Everything I'm searching for is for people who want to have their album artwork incorporated into a video. What I'm asking is if MKV can hold multiple images in succession, i.e. for videos like [this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Qx55EmiFadg):  where the video has very few actual "frames" (thus not taking up nearly as much space) because it's guaranteed to be 100% static content other than to change to the next page/image.

Unless modern compression algorithms make the amount of space saved in cases like this already negligible, I have no idea if that is the case --